# jQuery swap and hide div content based on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Firstly there are 101 questions similar to this one, however still unable to answer this question.

I am creating a similar interface to youtube, with video thumbnails on the right side and a pain playing pane.

My loop for displaying thumbnail images is as follows:

```
<?php function getVimeoThumb($id) {
    $data = file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$id.json");
    $data = json_decode($data);
    return $data[0]->thumbnail_medium;
} ?>

<div id="thumb">
    <img src="<?php echo getVimeoThumb($id);?>" alt="">   
    <h4><?php the_sub_field('child_title'); ?></h4>
</div>
```

My main feature video is displayed as follows:

```
<div id="feature">
    <h4 id="mainTitle"><?php the_sub_field('video_title'); ?></h4>
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php the_sub_field('video_id')?>" width="500" height="282"></iframe> 
</div> <!-- end of feature Container -->
```

The initial load will be conducted by PHP, however the DOM manipulation should be achieved by javascript.

**Questions**

1. How can I swap just the ID and text between these two divs.
2. I would also like to hide the thumbnail that has been clicked as it is shown in the feature frame.

Many thanks

Comment: jQuery has a replace() method attached to the string prototype, doesn't it?

Comment: But I wouldn't have a clue how to extract the ID from the string?

Comment: Replace the entire element's innerHTML?

Comment: It's not the entire innerHTML though, I need to extract the id from the image string and place it in the video string in the feature video.

Answer (score 2):

On your thumb, you could put the id on a `rel` on your `div` so you can retrieve it easily via jQuery:

```
`<div id="thumb" rel="your_id">...</div>`
```

And a `$('#thumb').attr('rel')` to get it.

Then you can create a JavaScript function that gives you the full URL from the ID and update your iframe src via `$('#feature iframe').attr('src','your_url')`